# Compiling with gcc including .h files?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, header-files

I'm trying to compile some AES implementation code from http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm, I got a txt file and splitted it up so I got 3 files:

> > ***encrypt.c***
> >     ***decrypt.c***
> >     ***rijndael.h***

Having all this 3 files in the same folder, I try to compile any of `encrypt.c` or `decrypt.c` files but it throws some errors about undefined functions which actually are in `rijndael.h`

I'm performing compilation this way:

`gcc -o encrypt encrypt.c` or `gcc -o decrypt decrypt.c`

And I get:

> > /tmp/cch6JvXT.o: In function `main`:
> >     encrypt.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `rijndaelSetupEncrypt`
> >     encrypt.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `rijndaelEncrypt`
> >     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But `rijndaelSetupEncrypt` and `rijndaelEncrypt` are in the rijndael.h file

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Depending on how you've split the source, you'll need to compile rijndael.c too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between an "undeclared function" error and an "undefined function" error. The first one is given when it can not find the prototype (meaning only the function header) of a function you've used, prototypes being usually put in the .h files and included in your .c files. The second error appears when it finds the prototype but not the definition of the function. The definition of a function (meaning the entire body of a function) can be fount either in a library or in another .c file that you should add to your compile command.

For "undefined function" error you could try

```
gcc -o enc_dec encrypt.c decrypt.c
```

if the function it cannot find is in one of the two .c files you've mentioned. 
If it's not, you might have forgotten to link a library.

**Later edit**: 
With the rijndael.c file:

```
gcc -o decrypt rijndael.c decrypt.c
gcc -o encrypt rijndael.c encrypt.c
```

It doesn't matter if rijndael.h hasn't got a `main` function. I suppose it has definitions for some of the functions used in decrypt.c and encrypt.c

Comment: You mean about rijndael.c not having a `main` function, right?

Comment: @Diego: Yes. You mentioned in a comment that rijndael.c doesn't have a `main` function.

Comment: Thanks @ionela.voinescu, I got to compile it so far... I'm really messed up with this stuff. I should try out this code but not getting good results. Could you give any help?

Comment: @Diego: You're welcome! You should post another question with the problems you're having with it. Maybe I or someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks, I just asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516738/testing-of-aes-algorithm-implementation-in-c.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in your example, you should have 4 files, encrypt.c decrypt.c rijndael.c and rijndael.h

So you have to compile rijndael.c and encrypt.c or same with decrypt together. .h files will be automatically used during compilation of c file which included the .h (header) file.

Comment: I tried this but then I realized there's not `main` function in rijndael.c