# Testing of AES algorithm implementation in C

Tags: c, aes, implementation

I've downloaded the code from this [site](http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm), compiled it and now trying to test it I got a few problems...

I generated two files from compilation **`encrypt`** and **`decrypt`** and instructions from the [site](http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm) are:

> The encryption program is called as follows:
>
> > **`encrypt  password  cryptofile`**
>
> It encrypts the standard input (padding it with spaces, if necessary), and writes the result to the specified cryptofile.
>
> The decryption program is called as follows:
>
> > **`decrypt  password  cryptofile`**
>
> It decrypts the cryptofile contents and sends the result (padded with spaces, if necessary) to the standard output.

I'm not getting this programs working the right way... I've tried these:

`./encrypt to_be_encrypted_file password_file encrypted_file`
`./encrypt to_be_encrypted_string password_string encrypted_file`

But all I'm getting is the prompt waiting for anything and any change in the ***encrypted file***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
./encrypt password_string encrypted_file < to_be_encrypted_file
```

The documentation says *It encrypts the standard input*.

And for `decrypt`:

```
./decrypt password_string encrypted_file > decrypted_file
```

because it says the result is send *to the standard output*.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely need to sharpen my knowledge about this C & UNIX world